# How to create a shade box that covers the whole footnotes area?

Tags: footnotes, boxes, shading

I would like to shade the whole footnote area (bottom of the page). Does anyone know, if it can be done ?

Edit : Using the answer provided, the text direction commands \setRL and \setLR, from the Bidi package, get ignored. Here is an example :

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\TeXXeTstate=1


\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{bidi}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{color}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily{\sbl}[Script=Hebrew]{SBLHebrew}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}


%colored footnotes

\def\colorftns#1{%
\nointerlineskip\hbox{\fboxsep0pt \colorbox{yellow}{\box#1}}}
\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule 
\def\footnoterule{\oldfootnoterule\let\unvbox\colorftns}

\begin{document}
\setRL
\H
h e b r e w t e x t   \setLR\footnote{a b c d e f} \setRL
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean with “shading” the boxing way as given by David or more a colour progression from background colour (e.g. white) into a different colour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This removes some of the flexible space between footnotes in order to box and colour the area, but is probably OK in practice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}


\def\colorftns#1{%
\nointerlineskip\hbox{\fboxsep0pt \colorbox{yellow}{\box#1}}}

\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
\def\footnoterule{\oldfootnoterule\let\unvbox\colorftns}



\begin{document}

aaa\footnote{one two three}

aaa\footnote{four five six}

aaa\footnote{red blue green

}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer provided is working is correspond to the question, but there seems to be some conflict with the "bidi" package, as the shading also changes the orientation of the text : the \setLR command is ignored. (The document is Right-to-left, but the footnotes are Left-to right)

Comment: Ah well as a workaround I guess you can put `\hbox{\beginR\fboxsep0pt \colorbox{yellow}{\box#1}}\endR}` ping me again if that doesn't work

Comment: Unfortunately the \beginR command seems to be ignored as well, it produces the same result.

Comment: If you can make a small bidi example and add it here or as a new question I'll try to look at the weekend (ping me in a comment if you add it here otherwise I wont see it:-)

Comment: I just put an example in the question. Thanks